# Lack of clarity in a VTC option

Tags: feature-request

So one of the "reasons that can be given" here for a VTC is:

> While this question may be related to philosophy or occur in a philosophical context, the question itself doesn't seem to be about philosophy, and is therefore not a good fit for our site.

I confess that I have perpetually been at a loss when it comes to understanding what sort of complaint this is. C.f. "While the question may be related to the Bible or occur in a Biblical context, the question itself doesn't seem to be about the Bible," or similar substitutions. I can *faintly* see how a question would not fit this SE if it was *only* "related to" philosophy or *only* "occurrent" in a philosophical context, but a question that was **both** related to philosophy **and** occurrent in said context, *would be about philosophy*, going off almost any plausible definition of "aboutness" at stake, I would think.

So I wonder whether we would be better off removing this as a VTC reason, here, since as it stands it doesn't seem very much like an actual "reason" so much as an obscure excuse.

Answer (score 1):

If a question is not about philosophy, even though it is philosophy adjacent, why would this not be the entirely appropriate tag?

Comment: My lack of understanding is about that kind of phrase, "philosophy-adjacent." For all sorts of topics, we have the "philosophy of" that topic, which seems like it's adjacent to that topic. For something to be philosophy-adjacent just seems to collapse to "is the philosophical side of the topic."